# Summing up multiple rows in two different tables

Tags: php

I have two tables with exactly similar fields. The first table is `originalentry` and the second table is `deprcharge`. The field for `originalentry` is as follows:

```
aid | desc | assetype | date | DoP | Misc | amt
```

Inside the `originalentry` table I have the following:

```
1  | Land @ borough | L & B | 2013/5/23 | 2013/2014 | xyz | 4000
2  | Fan | Electronics | 2013/8/20 | 2013/2014 | xyz | 3000
3  | Land @ orit | L & B | 2013/10/23 | 2013/2014 | xyz | 6000
4  | Land @ bradley | L & B | 2014/2/23 | 2014/2015 | xyz | 5000
```

For `deprcharge` table I have the following:

```
1  | depreciation chrg | L & B | 2013/12/23 | 2013/2014 | xyz | 1000
2  | depreciation chrg | Electronics | 2013/12/23 | 2013/2014 | xyz | 200
3  | depreciation chrg | L & B | 2014/12/23 | 2014/2015 | xyz | 2000
4  | depreciation chrg | Electronics | 2014/12/23 | 2014/2015 | xyz | 200
```

What I actually wanted was to have this records come out in php such that it will be grouped along `assetype` and `DoP @` let say year 2014/2015(current year) E.g.:

```
S/N | Assetype |Prev Yr| Current Yr| Total|Depr|NBV
1 |L & B | 10000|5000|15000|3000 |12000
2|Electronics|3000| 0 | 3000 | 400 | 2600
```

Though I have a third table called `asssetype` where all asset types are stored for reference.

Comment: Please use the tools to format this question. It's hard to read.

Comment: Could you specify the questions, i cant understand the subject, databases? WHat does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: I have those three tables in a mysql database and will like to sum up the figures in them to have what I actually wanted